# checking for the conditions if one of both are provided or none is provided

Tags: javascript

I have a condition where I am trying to format a date and if I do not choose any date, I am ending up with an invalid date/time error.

Here is my code:

```
console.log(filters.sDate != '' && filters.sDate != 'Last 30 days'); // false
console.log(filters.sDate != '') // false
console.log(filters.sDate != 'Last 30 days') // true
```

How can I fix it, what I am missing here?

Main condition which is doing its work :

```
this.filters.sDate = filters.sDate != '' && filters.sDate != 'Last 30 days' ? this.getDatefromFn(filters.sDate) : (filters.sDate != 'Last 30 days' ? this.DatefromFn(filters.sDate) : '');`
```

Comment: Please post the function `getDatefromFn`

Comment: `this.filters.sDate = filters.sDate == '' || filters.sDate == 'Last 30 days' ? '' : this.getDatefromFn(filters.sDate);`

Comment: that function is doing nothing, except converting the date to toISOString and returning it

Comment: "How can I fix it" Fix what? [Edit] your question to show a [mre]. Currently the code, when run, will throw errors regarding `filters` or `this.filters` or `this.getDateFromFn` being undefined. To fix those, define those values.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp please paste you answer, that post is working